# How to convert MySQL Group By to C# LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have the following code in MySQL

```
SELECT Query,SUM(TotalResults)
FROM TotalJobResults            
GROUP BY Query  
ORDER BY `SUM(TotalResults)`  DESC
```

I am trying to duplicate this function calling a MongoDB Collection in C# and cannot seem to actually understand it very well. I have the code below but it seems far from answering the problem,

```
var t = from q in _jobCollection.Find(_ => true).ToList().GroupBy(
                p => p.Query,
                p => p.TotalResults,
               (key, g) => new   { Query = key, Total = g.ToList().Sum() } 
                );
```

Thanks for any light you can shed on this!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it works if I put a select q on the end. hmm! my error

```
 var t = from q in _jobCollection.Find(_ => true).ToList().GroupBy(
            p => p.Query,
            p => p.TotalResults,
           (key, g) => new   { Query = key, Total = g.ToList().Sum() } 
            ) select q;
```